# Node(s) removal via Linq to XML how it works

Tags: linq-to-xml

The following fragment deletes "DpsRecord" elements which contain "Name" element which value contains "JOSE".  However, I don't understand how after applying Linq query to root and getting dpsRecords ( left side of query )  and then removing in dpsRecords, elements are also removed in root.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("input.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> dpsRecords = from elem in
                        root.Elements("DpsRecord")
                        where (((string)elem.Element("Name")).Contains("JOSE"))              
                        select elem;
foreach (XElement elem in dpsRecords)
{
   elem.Remove();
}
root.Save("output.xml");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the Remove method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx removes the node it is called on from its parent node.

Also take note that you don't need the foreach, you can do `dspRecords.Remove()`.

Comment: Certainly I understand that node is removed in dpsRecords which is subset of "root" ( XElement variable ) after applying query. It may be evident to you, but how removals in dpsRecords results in removals in root.

Comment: The Remove method you use in your code and I linked to removes a node from its parent node and not from any IEnmerable. So I don't see your problem, the method does what its documentation says it does, namely removing the node from its parent node, which is the `root` XElement node in your sample code. So whether you have an `IEnumerable<XElement>` or an `XElement[]` or a `List<XElement>`, if you call that Remove method on an XElement it removes the XElement from its parent node, not from any collection you are enumerating.